# Unable to establish connection over specific port in devices connected via VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, firewall, port-forwarding

I have an Ubuntu virtual machine on the Google Cloud Platform, which runs an OpenVPN server.

In my office, an Ubuntu laptop and a Windows PC act as OpenVPN Clients.

Hence, on the VPN, the following are the IP addresses:

- Virtual Machine: `10.8.0.1`
- Ubuntu laptop: `10.8.0.2`
- Windows PC: `10.8.0.3`

**I need a connection over port 102.** So, I opened the port 102 on all the three machines (Windows: adding a firewall rule, Ubuntu laptop: `ufw allow 102` and on VM: creating a firewall rule in VPC)

From the virtual machine, I used the `nmap` command to check if port 102 is reachable on 10.8.0.2. I used the following command:
`nmap -p 102 10.8.0.2` and the output is as shown below:

[image]

But, surprisingly, on the laptop when I check the open ports using 'ufw status', it shows that the port 102 is open as given below:

[image]

Then I thought that it was probably due to some port forwarding issue on my office router. But that doesn't seem to be the case, since I was able to see the following result for `nmap -p 102 10.8.0.2` (which is for the Windows PC behind the same office router):

[image]

So, this seems to be something related to Ubuntu firewall configurations I guess. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research into this, I found out why my `nmap` check showed port 102 is as 'closed'.

It seems that there should be some process/service that is actively running and listening on port 102 for that to be shown as 'open'.

I ran a dummy listener on the Ubuntu laptop using the following command:
`nc -l 102`

Now, if I run `nmap -p 102 10.8.0.2` from my Virtual Machine, I am able to see the port as 'open'.